# Allowing PPTP data through Vyatta firewall

Tags: vpn, firewall

I have a Vyatta firewall installed and I am now trying to connect to a PPTP host from one of my computers.

I allow TCP port 1723 through my firewall like this:

```
 rule 300 {
     action accept
     description "allowed trafic"
     destination {
         port 21-23,53,80,123,119,443,445,465,587,843,993,1025-65535
     }
     protocol tcp_udp
     state {
         new enable
     }
 }
```

and I added an extra rule for the GRE packets:

```
 rule 308 {
     action accept
     description "PPTP VPN"
     protocol gre
 }
```

Still, I get the message

> A connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the port for this connection was closed.

I tried the same VPN on another PC, on another network, where it worked, so the VPN is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I also had to allow incoming GRE packets:

```
set firewall name LAN-from-WAN rule 304 description "PPTP VPN"
set firewall name LAN-from-WAN rule 304 protocol gre
set firewall name LAN-from-WAN rule 304 action accept
```